# Combine and stack arrays in columns in julia

Tags: arrays, stack, julia

I am trying to combine two 1D arrays and stack them in columns,

```
a = [1 2 3]
b = [4 5 6]

# such that, they produce

     a b
c = [1 4
     2 5
     3 6]

# the python syntax for such operation is 
np.stack_column((a,b))
```

Please can someone suggest the julia syntax for this operation?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not 1-D arrays. They are 2-D arrays with the first dimension being one. `a = [1,2,3]` is the correct syntax for 1-D array. 1-D arrays are treated as vertical vectors. To stack two 1-D arrays, you just need `c = [a b]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On of my friend suggested two ways of executing this,

```
1.   transpose(vcat(a,b))
     hcat(a', b')
  
2.   reshape(hcat(a,b), (3,2))
```

## Both will create an output of

```
 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
1  4
2  5
3  6

Comment: `transpose(vcat(a,b))` is the fastest/ most memory efficient of these.

Comment: or shorter `[a; b]'`